# Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row '0'

Tags: c#, json, model-view-controller, datatables, .net-core

I'm developing my DataTables app with .NET. While trying to run my app I'm getting this error message:

> DataTables warning: table id=tbl_NameValue - Requested unknown parameter 'Name' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

My HTML:

```
<div class="row container">
    <table id="tbl_NameValue" class="display" style="direction:rtl;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value </th>
                <th>GroupName </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tbl_NameValue').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "/BaseInfo/NameValueSelectAll",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns":
        [{
                data: 'Name'
            }, {
                data: 'Value'
            }, {
                data: 'GroupName'
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.19/i18n/Persian.json"
        }
    });
});
```

My C#:

```
public IActionResult NameValueSelectAll() {

    List < NameValueModel > result;
    using(NameValueDA dataAccess = new NameValueDA()) {
        var dt = dataAccess.SelectAll();
        result = this.NameValueGetList(dt);
    }
    string tmp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
    return Json(new {
        data = tmp
    });
}

public List < NameValueModel > NameValueGetList(DataTable datatable) {
    List < NameValueModel > result = new List < NameValueModel > ();
    result = (from DataRow dr in datatable.Rows
        select new NameValueModel() {
        Name = Convert.ToString(dr["NMVL_Name"]),
        Value = Convert.ToInt32(dr["NMVL_Value"]),
        GroupName = Convert.ToString(dr["NMVL_GroupName"])

    }).ToList();
    return result;
}
```

[My JSON format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHnCz.png)

Comment: If your back end returns array of entries, which correspond to your rows, you need to specify `ajax.dataSrc: ''` option.

Comment: i've added my back end structure i precipitated more info please , how i must use this option?

Comment: It looks confusing to me: if you return to AJAX call the string `{data = ...}` that doesn't seem to be valid JSON - you must use `:` rather than `=`. If it's just a misunderstanding from my end, and your JSON in fact is something like `[{"Name":"somename", "Value":"somevalue",...},{...}]`, you need to set `ajax:{dataSrc:'',...}` within your datatable initialization section (`$('#tbl_NameValue').DataTable({...})`).

Comment: at this moment i code these line: `string strmsg = "[{\"Name\":1,\"Value\":\"suresh\",\"GroupName\":\"chennai\"}]";
            var test = Json(strmsg);`  and i add this to my options : "dataSrc": "" but issue has not solve yet

Comment: You may purge `<table></table>` inner HTML, so it stays just `<table id="tbl_NameValue" class="display" style="direction:rtl;"></table>`. Is the error any different now or it stays just the same?

Comment: nop nothing happens i know the problem is how i convert my list of object to json but i dont know how to fix this in ajax datatables dos not recognize my json array

Comment: I apply these changes `JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
            settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            return Json(new {data= result },settings);` and this new error showed _DataTables warning: table id=tbl_NameValue - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1_  whta is the proper way to convert list of object to json in .netcore mvc 2.1 ??